# Will there be any issues if I initialize inside a getter?

Tags: java, initialization, singleton, getter-setter

I work in travel domain. The `Main` class is created for example. The beans are used in web-java-project. The code below is working fine as expected. Still I doubt if there's any unknown problem which may happen in future (the `Vechiles` class is used widely in the application).

`Singleton` should be attained through `constructor` but in this case I did it through `getter`. Also the `setter` is kept as it is (so I am not sure it can be called as Singleton or not.

**Car**

```
public class Car {
    private int wheelCount;

    public int getWheelCount() {
        return wheelCount;
    }

    public void setWheelCount(int wheelCount) {
        this.wheelCount = wheelCount;
    }
}
```

**Vehicles**

```
public class Vehicles {
    private Car car;

    public Car getCar() {
        if(car == null){
            Car newCar = new Car();
            this.car = newCar;
            return newCar;
        }
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
        Car car1 = vehicles.getCar();
        car1.setWheelCount(3);
        System.out.println(vehicles.getCar().getWheelCount());
        
        Car anotherCar = vehicles.getCar();
        vehicles.setCar(anotherCar);
        vehicles.getCar().setWheelCount(4);
        System.out.println(vehicles.getCar().getWheelCount());
        
        Car car_withNew = new Car();
        vehicles.setCar(car_withNew);

        System.out.println(vehicles.getCar().getWheelCount());
    }
}
```

**Output**: (comes as expected)

```
3
4
0
```

**Requirement**:
`vehicles.getCar().setWheelCount(x);` should be possible. Otherwise, each time, I need to check, whether a `Car` exists or not. If does not exists, create one with `new` keyword and then set it with `setter`.

Should initialize inside getter like this?
**One problem I found** :
Note: Usually The `Vehicles` might contain a `Car` or might not. But in this case, the `Vehicles` will always contain a Car (when getter is called) !!! So, in that case, with the given Car model, there's no option to check whether it is NULL or not (car exists or not). It will never be NULL.

Is there any other problems?

Comment: That has nothing to do with a Singleton at all. And the problem you mentioned isn't so much a problem as just how you designed your code. What is you main thought process behind what you are doing? What did you try to achieve by initializing the car in the getter if it is null? I would have guessed "He never wants that method to return null and instead always a car" but your mentioned "problem" contradicts that.

Comment: I just edited with requirement @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: For me Getters should only be used to return values of the class. If it's required that `Car` is never `null`, then add it to the constructor and force a valid instance of `Car`. `Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(new Car())` also communicates the process more clearly

Comment: I think you should fully step back. What are actually trying to model here? Why does a Vehicle instance have a Car instance as MEMBER? Wouldnt that rather be something to use inheritance? Like an abstract base class Vehicle, and the Car class extending that? The abstractions that you model should represent reality, and be helpful. I really have a hard time seeing this in your design.

Comment: And unrelated: learn about Java naming conventions. "_" is for SOME_CONSTANT only. Variable/method/... names all go camelCase, without "_" in them.

Comment: You should probably rethink your models. Conceptually, a `Car` is a `Vehicule` and has `Wheels`. Excepted a loaded trailer, I don't expect a `Car`to be a part of a `Vehicule`

Comment: @GhostCat & @RatzzFatzz , The classes already exists in the project. Not created by me. It's an old project and is not at all possible to make such changes. What you mentioned is right, the abstraction should have done in a right method. It is not `Vehicle` it is `Vehicles` I mis-spelled it before (now edited). There are other vechiles than car.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call your code a `Singleton` because singletons refer to a single instance (object) of a given class, maintained throughout the whole application runtime. There's nothing stopping your code from creating multiple instances of the `Car` class, so in a sense the `car` is not a singleton (and having and using multiple instances of a `car` is implied by the `setter` method in `Vehicles`).

What I see you are trying to achieve, is to ensure that the call chain `vehicles.getCar().getWheelCount()` never throws a `NullPointerException`, and that will be true.

Your code may work as desired when in a single-thread scenario, however may lead to undesirable outcomes when you have multiple threads calling `getCar()` on the same `vehicles` object. Imagine you have two threads that hold the same `vehicles` object, and they both call `getCar()` at the same time. In such a situation, it is possible that both see `car == null` as `true`, and they both create a `car` object. Then the last thread to call `this.car = newCar` will set the `car` field in the `vehicles` object, overwriting the value.

Having said that, you can think about what exact purpose `Vehicles` needs to serve: is it a factory for cars (i.e. construct but don't hold references), or does it need to hold all `car` objects that have been created ever (in that sense a single `Car` instance is not sufficient).

If it can serve as a factory, then you can simplify `Vehicles` by simply providing a method `newCar` that returns a newly created `Car` instance.

If it should hold cars as references, then you should keep a `collection` of cars, and make sure this collection can be concurrently modified.

Comment: Nice one, especially the part about concurrency!

Answer (score 1):

> Will there be any issues if I initialize inside a getter?

This is sort of an "opinionated" question, but there is a simple factual answer to that: the conventions within your team matter more than "more global" conventions.

Meaning: conceptually, a `getter()` should be exactly that, a method that "reads" a value and provides that to the caller. In C++ terms, you would think of a `const` method that does **not** alter the state of the object it is called on. But a key aspect of getter methods is: they can be more than a simple field access. The fact that clients do `x = foo.getX()` instead of `x = foo.x` allows for exactly that: doing "other things" besides returning a value.

So: yes, `getCar()` sometimes creating a `Car` object might be surprising to some readers, but when **your** team understands such aspects, and agrees "this is what we want", then that is okay for you. Because your team thought about it, and made that decision.

Of course: the more meaningful solution would be to **not call it a getter** in the first place: why not rename that method, and call it `getWithCreateIfNeeded()` or something alike?!

Also of course, the other answer is spot on: the code you are showing here is **not** thread safe. Period. When used in a multi threaded environment, *that* is the only thing that can create **real** damage.